# R data.table join with roll

Tags: r, data.table

```
dd = data.table(a = c(1,1), b = c(1,2), v = c(1, NA))
dd
#    a b  v
# 1: 1 1  1
# 2: 1 2 NA
setkey(dd, a,b)
dd[.(1,2), roll = TRUE, rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE)]
#    a b  v
# 1: 1 2 NA
```

What have I missed here? Why isn't `v` carried forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rolling join doesn't need to do rolling here as you are matching exact row `(1, 2)`. Rolling matching is made when there is no match on actual values, in your case it has exact match. See below example which, I modified `dd` so there is no match on `.(1,2)`.

```
library(data.table)
dd = data.table(a = c(1,1), b = c(1,3), v = c(1, NA))
dd[.(1,2), roll = TRUE, rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE)]
#   a b v
#1: 1 2 1
```

See `?data.table`//`roll` (emphasis mine):

> When `i` is a `data.table` and its row matches **to all but the last `x` join column**, and its value in the last `i` join column falls in a gap (including after the last observation in `x` for that group), then:
>
> - `+Inf` (or `TRUE`) rolls the prevailing value in `x` forward. It is also known as last observation carried forward (LOCF)
>
> ...